# updating many records (batch update) in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have class A and class B.
Now class A has Set of B.

```
class A{
 Set<B> bset //

}
```

bset.size()  can be > 100 or  > 500 etc

Now i want to change one filed of all B which corresponds to A 
Eg:update B set Bfield = x where id IN (1,2,3);

1)What will be the query in hibernate?
2)1,2,3 are ids of B (B.id).
3)How can i retrive all ids of B that corresponds to A in the format required by the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correct

```
update B set b.field = :newValue where b.parent = :parentA
```

Comment: is there a way of achieving this using Criterion instead of native SQL or HQL?

Comment: The Criteria API is just about queries.

Comment: sorry. Let me rephrase that: if I use session.save(Object) on a set of objects, all of them having only 1 field modified to the same value, is it possible to have hibernate to issue one batch update rather than one update per Object?

Comment: Of course, just let all the `save`s happen in one transaction.

Comment: from what I observe, there are still N SQL queries happening, as it has been logged via `show_sql = true`

Comment: Does anything gets read from the database after each update statement? Hibernate flushes session cache every time data is read from the database.